# MS Access getting the latest record from two tables

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a MS Access table that contains two tables

1. List of Files
2. File transfers

In List of files - every new physical file that is created is given a unique reference number (File Reference field) together with a full name about the subject.

In File transfers - every time the file is transferred from one person to another, the movement is recorded by entering the (Reference - field). The files are moved a lot of times throughout the year. So this file traces the full movement of such files.

I created a relationship in MS Access that identified (File Reference field) and (Reference - field) that link the two tables together showing that these are a bridge that link them together.

I would like to create a new query that shows a list of files together with their corresponding reference number, showing the latest person holding each and every file. E.g. if I have file reference 123/ABC and this has been transferred say 10 times; and Peter is currently the person with the physical file in his hands. I would like for the query to display Peter's name rather than all the transfers of file 123/ABC.

I would like to have this for every file created in the List of Files table.

If it helps this is my MySQL query in MS Access

`SELECT [List of Files].Reference, [List of Files].[Full Name], [File Transfers].User, [File Transfers].[Movement Date]
FROM [List of Files] INNER JOIN [File Transfers] ON [List of Files].Reference = [File Transfers].[File Reference]
ORDER BY [File Transfers].[Movement Date] DESC;`

Comment: This sounds like a job for source control.  Have you investigated replacing your access db system with Perforce or another proffessional control managmenet solution?

Comment: No. I haven't we're on a tight budget and we want a system that everyone with MS Access skills to be able to manage it.